# Intercepting flash XHR requests by chrome.webRequest API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Basically, I want my extension to be able to read all data that is sent and recieved by flash elements on pages that user is viewing.

Is this possible? 
I assumed that yes, because adblock addon seems to be able to block commercials inside flash, but after playing around for a while, I found no way to get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried using Cross- Origin XMLHttpRequest? you can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first request cross-origin pemissions. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: @d.datul1990 Thats not what Im trying to do. I have no trouble with sending requests. What I need, is to _view_ requests that are sent by flash elements on 3rd party web sites, which are not under my control.